# Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error time out

Tags: url-rewriting, netflix-zuul, http-status-code-500

I am completely new to zuul, but I am facing a challenge I can't seem to overcome due to some changes we made in the configuration.

Zuul is being used simply to re-write some urls in this case, nothing more. It works fine in all sorts of other environments and used to work in this one until we made these changes.

The zuul config looks something like this..

```
spring:
  profiles: development
zuul:
  routes:
    fakebank:
          path: /fake-bank/rest/projects/fakebank/**
          url:  https://dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/rest
    fakebank2:
          path: /rest/projects/fakebank/**
          url:  https://dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/res
```

However, when I visit the URL that is to be re-written, for example `https://dev-api.fakebank.com/fake-bank/rest/projects/fake-bank/health-check`, I just keep getting the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jun 23 17:48:24 UTC 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
connect timed out
```

Does anyone have any idea or can point me in a good direction to start walking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this on my own and figured I would post the answer out here for others to consume.

In the end, there was an error in the re-write configuration.  Sort of.
  I noticed there was no SSL configuration to speak of for the tomcat server.  So changing the https to http solved the problem. I would imagine that if I were to setup SSL on the tomcat instance that it may start working.  If I wanted to use SSL, I would have alter the URL again to include port 443 as shown in the example below.

Example :

```
spring: 
profiles: development 
zuul: 
routes: 
fakebank: path: /fake-bank/rest/projects/fakebank/** 

- url: https:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/rest 
(Non-SSL)
+ url: http:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/rest 
Or (if I setup SSL)
+ url: https:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com:443/office-365/rest 

fakebank2: path: /rest/projects/fakebank/** 
- url: https:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/res
(Non-SSL)
+ url: http:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com/office-365/res
Or (if I setup SSL)
+ url: https:// dev-fakebank-api.fkebnk.com:443/office-365/res
```

Hope this helps someone else that finds themselves in this situation.

Thanks,